# Regular expression to match strings with embedded spaces

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to write a regular expression but I can't pass the words space

I have a data file like this (generated by another utility)

```
* field      : 100
blahbla      : <Set>
scree        : <what>
.Cont.asasd  :
Othreaol     : Value, Other value
Point->IP    : 0.0.0.0 Port 5060
```

The pattern has to match and capture data like this

```
"field" "100"
"blahbla" "<Set>"
"scree" "<what>"
".Cont.asasd" ""
"Othreaol" "Value, Other value"
```

My early solution is

```
/^([\s\*]+)([\w]+[\s\.\-\>]{0,2}[\w]+)(\s*\:\s)(.*)/
```

but I have problem with some strings like

```
Z.15 example : No
```

the space stops the pattern from matching

```
H.25 miss here : No
```

same thing here

Comment: What's the programming language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why the `Point->IP` line is omitted from your example output, but something like the code below should suit you.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
  next unless /([^\s*].+?)\s*:\s*(.*?)\s*$/;
  printf qq("%s" "%s"\n), $1, $2;
}

__DATA__

  * field      : 100
  blahbla      : <Set>
  scree        : <what>
  .Cont.asasd  :
  Othreaol     : Value, Other value
  Point->IP    : 0.0.0.0 Port 5060
  Z.15 example : No
  H.25 miss here : No
```

**output**

```
"field" "100"
"blahbla" "<Set>"
"scree" "<what>"
".Cont.asasd" ""
"Othreaol" "Value, Other value"
"Point->IP" "0.0.0.0 Port 5060"
"Z.15 example" "No"
"H.25 miss here" "No"
```

Comment: your solution is very short my final is: `/^(\s{2,2}\*?)(\w+[\.\-\>\=]*[\s]?\w+[\.\-\>\=]*[\s]?\w+[\.\-\>\=]*[\s]*?\w*)(\s+:)(.*)/` :P thanks

Answer (score 5):

There are some complicated answers here. I think I'd use a simple [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/split.html):

```
while( <DATA> ) {
    chomp;
    my( $field, $value ) = split /\s*:\s*/, $_, 2;
    print "Field [$field] value [$value]\n";
    }

__DATA__
* field      : 100
blahbla      : <Set>
scree        : <what>
.Cont.asasd  :
Othreaol     : Value, Other value
Point->IP    : 0.0.0.0 Port 5060
```

This gives:

```
Field [* field] value [100]
Field [blahbla] value [<Set>]
Field [scree] value [<what>]
Field [.Cont.asasd] value []
Field [Othreaol] value [Value, Other value]
Field [Point->IP] value [0.0.0.0 Port 5060]
```

From there, I'd filter the names and values as needed instead of trying to do it all in a single regex:

```
my @pairs = 
    grep { $_->[0] !~ /->/ }                   # filter keys
    map  { $_->[0] =~ s/\A\*\s+//; $_ }        # transform keys
    map  { chomp; [ split /\s*:\s*/, $_, 2 ] } # parse line 
    <DATA>;

use Data::Printer;
p @pairs;

__DATA__
* field      : 100
blahbla      : <Set>
scree        : <what>
.Cont.asasd  :
Othreaol     : Value, Other value
Point->IP    : 0.0.0.0 Port 5060
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to separate the values by colon, use the complement of *that* character in your regex for all those characters before the split.

```
my $regex 
    = qr{
         ( # v- no worry, this matches the first non-space, non-colon
           [^\s:]      
           (?> [^:\n]* # this matches all non-colon chars on the line
               [^\s:]  # match the last non-space, non-colon, if there
           )?          # but possibly not there
         )             # end group

         \s*           # match any number of whitespace
         :             # match the colon
         \s*           # followed by any number of whitespace

         ( \S          # Start second capture with any non space
           (?> .*      # anything on the same line
               \S      # ending in a non-space
           )?          # But, possibly not there at all
         |             # OR 
         )             # nothing - this gives the second capture as an 
                       # empty string instead of an undef
    }x;

while ( <$in> ) { 
    $hash{ $1 } = $2 if m/$regex/;
}
```

`%hash` then looks like this:

```
{ '* field'        => '100'
, '.Cont.asasd'    => ''
, 'H.25 miss here' => 'No'
, Othreaol         => 'Value, Other value'
, 'Point->IP'      => '0.0.0.0 Port 5060'
, 'Z.15 example'   => 'No'
, blahbla          => '<Set>'
, scree            => '<what>'
}
```

Of course, as I begin to think on it, if you could be assured of a `/\s+:\s+/` pattern or at least a `/\s{2,}:\s{2,}/` pattern, it might be simpler to just `split` the line like so:

```
while ( <$in> ) { 
    if ( my ( $k, @v ) 
         = grep {; length } split /\A\s+|\s+\z|(\s+:\s+)/
       ) { 
        shift @v; # the first one will be the separator
        $hash{ $k } = join( '', @v );
    }
}
```

It does the same thing, at does not have to do nearly as much backtracking to trim results. And it ignores escaped colons without a whole lot more syntax, because it has to be a *bare* colon surrounded by spaces. You could just simply add the following to the if block:

```
$k =~ s/(?<!\\)(\\\\)*\\:/$1:/g;
```

Comment: He *does* use a colon in his regex